# tab marking in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I pressed in visual studio 2005 ctro+w, and then every tab in my code become:

```
-> -> -> ->
```

How do I get rid of these strange symbols?

Comment: I though they look a little bit more like → → →

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried pressing ctrl+w again?

In VS2008, the option is Edit -> Advanced -> View Whitespace. Not sure if it's the same in 2005.

Comment: The Edit, advanced, view whitespace worked.  Thanks a whole lot.